# identity server how to custom login page

Tags: identityserver3

I need to change and customize the login page, implementing the

> "IviewService"

isn't not good enough, i need the full layout.

any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

Implementing a custom `IViewService` is [exactly how you change the full layout](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customizingViews.html).

However, if you want to change only the login page, you can do so by adding your own html that implements the same angular logic as the [existing login page](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/login.html) and adding it to a folder named `templates` with a file name of `_login.html`.

If you want to modify the [layout](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/layout.html) (the headers) then you need to do the same this time naming the file `_Layout.html`.

This is all detailed in the [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/DefaultViewService.html), with the above listed as "Replacing partial views".

Comment: I was looking all over the place for the "existing" views so that I could just modify one or two little things.  The "existing login page" is what I was missing.  Thx.